# change the separator of a paste commande

Tags: bash, find, paste, xargs

I have a probleme to parse the result of my commande :

```
find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 bash -c 'paste -d " " <(md5sum "$@") <(sha1sum "$@") <(sha256sum "$@") <(du -lh "$@")' bash
```

which give me this :

```
c37967f401d16fa37736cbe08809d3d66c8f516a  /etc/vmware-tools/resume-vm-default 1aae06b3e3db93584b27ddf24ecd58e7a080f33c160f0186ec9b50ab32bc9a92  /etc/vmware-
tools/resume-vm-default 4.0K    /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

But I don't want spaces to separate them because it's impossible to parse them because of the spaces that appears in the file name.

how can i get something like this?

```
md5; sha1; sha256, size, path
```

I don't find how to change the separator between my values.

I tried :

```
 find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 bash -c 'paste -d " " <(md5sum "$@" | printf ";$1;") <(sha1sum "$@" | printf ";$2;") <(sha256sum "$@" | printf ";$3;") <(du -lh "$@" | printf ";$4;")' bash
```

but it print only the path...

I tried :

```
 find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 bash -c 'paste -d ";" <(md5sum "$@") <(sha1sum "$@") <(sha256sum "$@") <(du -lh "$@")' bash
```

which is almost why in want. but mistake appears like ^ in my sha1...

Also I don't want to get the file path 5 times.

do did this :

```
find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 bash -c 'paste -d ";" <(md5sum "$@" | awk "{print $1;}") <(sha1sum "$@" | awk "{print $1;}") <(sha256sum "$@" | awk "{print $1;}") <(du -lh "$@"| awk "{print $1;}")' bash
```

but it returns a tons of error.

Comment: `paste` usually has several input files and combines them. You are feeding into `paste` only stdin. Not sure what you want to achieve here.

Comment: what whould make my question clearer ?

Comment: By concentrating on the paste command itself. The `find` and `xargs` does not seem to be relevant to your problem.  If i understand you right, you have a huge set of lines in stdin, and you want to combine the lines into a single line, where the original stdin lines are now separated by a semicolon. Right?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Due to process substitution. you do have more than one input. In this case, why don't you simply use `-d';'` on`paste`?

Comment: What about `paste -d ';'`? And then the first word in a record is the hash or size and the rest is the file name.

Comment: I tried to modifie paste -d ';' I the commande I talk about in my question but its doesn't do anything ? why ?

Comment: Beware the quotes. In your context you should use `paste -d ";"`, not `paste -d ';'`.

Comment: paste -d ";" is actually a good way of solving one problem

Comment: `md5; sha1; sha256, size, path`: are you 100% sure that using a mix of semi-colons and commas, plus spaces after them, will ease the parsing of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your complicated use of `xargs` and `paste` you could use a simpler `bash` loop:

```bash
$ declare -a r s t u
$ while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    r=( $(md5sum "$file") )
    s=( $(sha1sum "$file") )
    t=( $(sha256sum "$file") )
    u=( $(du -lh "$file") )
    printf "%s; %s; %s, %s, %s\n" "${r[0]}" "${s[0]}" "${t[0]}" "${u[0]}" "$file"
done < <( find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 )
```

The `r`, `s`, `t` and `u` indexed arrays are just a way to easily isolate the first word of a command's output.

Note that the output format you chose is probably not that easy to parse because it mixes semi-colons and commas and adds a space after them. Not mentioning the possibility of file names with semi-colons, commas or newlines. A cleaner output format would stick with the NUL separator (the only character that you cannot find in a file name):

```bash
$ declare -a r s t u
$ while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    r=( $(md5sum "$file") )
    s=( $(sha1sum "$file") )
    t=( $(sha256sum "$file") )
    u=( $(du -lh "$file") )
    printf "%s\0%s\0%s\0%s\0%s\0" "${r[0]}" "${s[0]}" "${t[0]}" "${u[0]}" "$file"
done < <( find / -type f -not \( -path '/dev/*' -or -path '/proc/*' -or -path '/sys/devices/*' \) -print0 )
```

Comment: I dont want my md5sum to give me the path

Comment: I just want the hash

Comment: So why do you leave the paths in the expected output you show?

Comment: let me correct that

Comment: Please edit your question and show the exact output you want, instead of something else.

Comment: Love the use of arrays to parse out the hashes!

Comment: Deleted my answer as not really adding enough of value that isn't already here. The only thing I'd mention is that there are other ways than this array-based parsing ([c.f. here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) ), but they aren't *better* unless they make more sense to the person maintaining the code. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

A demo using my own files on how you can process all of them in one fell swoop in awk :

> ```
> gfind . -name "vg*.mp4" -print0 | 
> xargs -0 -n 100 -P 8 sh -c 'for arg; do 
>
> mawk  -v __="${arg}" -- '\''
>
> BEGIN { RS = FS = "^$" (ORS=_) 
> } END { 
>     (___=" for idx in 1; do "\
>          "( md5sum    -b "(__)" & ); "\
>          "( sha1sum   -b "(__)" & ); "\
>          "( sha256sum -b "(__)" & ); "\
>          "( du -lh       "(__)" & ) done | gcat -") | getline _;
>
>      close(___); print _ }'\''; done ' _
> ```

```
783M    ./vg1.mp4
58662ec3912c05db0d23df0bf085f3e537d24bf1 *./vg1.mp4
b18c18818677684ee1b1f1e730acc42d *./vg1.mp4
60796bbeba76d695c47a697e47398b063c898a3baa8cac0cda163e00a75d8337 *./vg1.mp4

205M    ./vg3.mp4
64712648eb0200399f745cb509acb4bba6638fe2 *./vg3.mp4
05533b330bd6f9f941c3734b7e86dba1 *./vg3.mp4
00bb3b8d45ae14505fac84809c8bbfd51a8cdddd44c13e44237357b5987f8597 *./vg3.mp4

160M    ./vg2.mp4
8b0e8c09321994a5f3c46a71d498f6df226c7e0d *./vg2.mp4
75a519a04a15632b07f9bb8dece2ad83 *./vg2.mp4
cb07ed28cad5f30690aad63d86c5b1c9dd45dfcbd101c8ae79c7f900b755022b *./vg2.mp4
```

You'll need to add the necessary file name escaping at the shell, and any quotations for them.

Because I've brute force thrown them all into background processes, most likely the incoming order wouldn't be the same, and you'll have to sort them out afterwards.

Luckily, their hash output lengths are so drastically different it should be rather obvious. And I'm sure there are some inefficiencies in the `posix shell` part of this script, since i hardly use it at all.